# excel pass cell content to udf as range argument

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm currently trying to pass to a user defined function in excel the contents of an cell as argument.

Namely, i calculate the range i'm interested in a cell, where i get something like this "sheet1!X17:X37".

Now i want to pass this cell (e.g. A1) to a udf. For example i want in B1 to have "=myfunction(A1)" as opposed to "=myfunction(sheet1!X17:X37).

Any ideas?

My function is like this:

```
Public Function ConcatItNoDuplicities(ByVal cellsToConcat As Range) As String
    ConcatItNoDuplicities = ""
    If cellsToConcat Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim result As String
    For Each oneCell In cellsToConcat.Cells
        Dim cellValue As String
        cellValue = Trim(oneCell.Value)
        If cellValue <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, result, cellValue, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then _
                result = result & cellValue & ","
        End If
    Next oneCell
    If Len(result) > 0 Then _
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    ConcatItNoDuplicities = result
End Function
```

Best
T

Comment: Um... maybe I am missing something, but the concatenation of one cell is just that cell, no?  so would this not be the same as `=A1`

Comment: Actually A1 contains the range i want to concatenate and i want to use as argument in my function the contents of A1, not to concatenate A1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indirect:

```
=ConcatItNoDuplicities(INDIRECT(A1))
```

Comment: Many thanks! That was so simple..., cannot belive how much time i've spent on it.

Comment: @theodorcarp please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

Say **A1** contains text that looks like a cell block address.  This tiny UDF() does a simple concatenation of the target:

```
Public Function TakeOneStepBeyond(rng1 As Range) As String
    Dim rng2 As Range, r As Range

    Set rng2 = Range(rng1.Value)

    TakeOneStepBeyond = ""
    For Each r In rng2
        TakeOneStepBeyond = TakeOneStepBeyond & r.Value
    Next r
End Function
```

[image]